# How to get revive adserver impressions and clicks form its tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was used revive [adserver](http://www.revive-adserver.com/) to track banner impressions and clicks. And then 
I want to access impression and click by my phpmyadmin not from adserver admin panel.

This is my access query

```
SELECT sum(`impressions`) FROM `rv_data_summary_ad_hourly` WHERE `ad_id`=6 AND `date_time` >= '2015-10-26' AND `date_time` <= '2015-11-01'
```

-
Here is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rv_data_summary_ad_hourly` (
  `data_summary_ad_hourly_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `creative_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `requests` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `impressions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clicks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `conversions` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_basket_value` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_num_items` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_revenue` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_cost` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_techcost` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_summary_ad_hourly_id`),
  KEY `rv_data_summary_ad_hourly_date_time` (`date_time`),
  KEY `rv_data_summary_ad_hourly_ad_id_date_time` (`ad_id`,`date_time`),
  KEY `rv_data_summary_ad_hourly_zone_id_date_time` (`zone_id`,`date_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16136 ;
```

But impressions and clicks result is little different .I want result exactly same as adserver admin panel.

This is view results of  phpmyadmin 
[image]

-
This is view results of revive adserver admin panel
[image]

Comment: What is the difference you are getting between them?

Comment: Please look and see again my question please. I have been edited and uploaded two different results of photo

Comment: have you checked with timezone

Comment: How could I check it please?

Comment: am not sure check in `rv_account_preference_assoc`

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Now I found solution because revive adserver change datetime to UTC format (SqlBuilder.php) before search so my Mysql query need to change that format. Thank you for you clue @VijayaSankarN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the timezone in Revive adserver. Change the MySQL query to match it.

[Extract from comments, might help other users with similar problem]